# Integral involving a floor function

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I've been thinking about this problem for a bit:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \int_1^n \log x \left( \left\lfloor \frac{n}{x-1} \right\rfloor- \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left\lfloor \frac{n}{x^k} \right\rfloor\right) \, dx.$$

If we assume we can apply the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem, this should tend to a 0, but I haven't  found an appropriate dominating function (not even a useful one for GDCT). Instead, I was able to show it is between 0 and 1. Anyone have any thoughts?

$\textbf{Edit:}$ I figured it would be best to explain the motivation. On Wikipedia for "Euler-Mascheroni constant", it provides the identity
$$\sum_{p \leq n} \frac{\log p}{p-1} = \log n - \gamma + o(1),$$
without citing a source. Because of this, I took it upon myself to provide my own proof (once in a while, I'll try to look and see if I could find it). Recalling Legendre's formula for $n!$

$$\log n! = \sum_{p \leq n} \log p \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left \lfloor \frac{n}{p^k} \right \rfloor,$$
after a series of manipulations, we end up with the expression

$$\sum_{p \leq n} \frac{\log p}{p-1} - \log n = \frac{1}{n} \log \frac{n!}{n^n} + \frac{1}{n} \sum_{p \leq n} \log p \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left \{ \frac{n}{p^k}\right\}.$$

An acquaintance of mine and I were able to show $\displaystyle \frac{1}{n} \sum_{p \leq n} \log p \left\{ \frac{n}{p-1} \right\} \to 1-\gamma$; so then we consider the expression

\begin{align*}
& \sum_{p \leq n} \log p \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left \{ \frac{n}{p^k}\right\}\\
&= \sum_{p \leq n} \log p \left\{ \frac{n}{p-1} \right\} + \sum_{p \leq n} \log p \left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left \{ \frac{n}{p^k}\right\}- \left\{ \frac{n}{p-1} \right\}\right)
\end{align*}

If we assume $\displaystyle \sum_{p \leq n} \log p \left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left \{ \frac{n}{p^k}\right\}- \left\{ \frac{n}{p-1} \right\}\right) = o(n)$, then we have
$$\sum_{p \leq n} \frac{\log p}{p-1} - \log n \to  -1 + 1 -\gamma = - \gamma,$$
which is the result we want. Thus, the task becomes proving

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{p \leq n} \log p \left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left \{ \frac{n}{p^k}\right\}- \left\{ \frac{n}{p-1} \right\}\right) = 0.$$
Since $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left\{ \frac{n}{p^k} \right\}- \left\{ \frac{n}{p-1} \right\} = \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p-1} \right\rfloor - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^k} \right\rfloor$, one way of bounding the sum is
\begin{align*}
0&\leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{p \leq n} \log p \left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left \{ \frac{n}{p^k}\right\}- \left\{ \frac{n}{p-1} \right\}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{p \leq n} \log p \left(\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p-1} \right\rfloor - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^k} \right\rfloor\right) \\
&\leq \frac{1}{n} \int_1^n \log x \left( \left\lfloor \frac{n}{x-1} \right\rfloor- \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left\lfloor \frac{n}{x^k} \right\rfloor\right) \, dx,
\end{align*}
which explains why we are considering the integral at hand. I have tried another bound that showed the limit lies in the interval $[0,1]$ but, for our purposes, this is insufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Before I proceed, let me preface and reiterate that the original motivation was to show
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{p \leq n} \log p \left(\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p-1} \right\rfloor - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^k} \right\rfloor\right) = 0,$$
and one direction that was considered was the evaluation of the limit of the integral in the original post
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\int_1^n \log(x)\left(\left\lfloor \frac{n}{x-1} \right\rfloor - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left\lfloor \frac{n}{x^k} \right\rfloor\right) \, dx.$$
After going back to drawing board, this direction is no longer considered since another proof was provided through different means. That said, we will now prove our original problem.

> $\textbf{Theorem:}$ Let $p$ denote a prime number. Then $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{p \leq n} \log p \left(\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p-1} \right\rfloor - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^k} \right\rfloor\right) = 0.$$

Using the fact $\lfloor x \rfloor = x - \{ x\}$, observe we have

\begin{align*}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{p \leq n} \log p \left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left \{ \frac{n}{p^k}\right\}- \left\{ \frac{n}{p-1} \right\}\right) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{p \leq n} \log p \left(\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p-1} \right\rfloor - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^k} \right\rfloor\right).\end{align*}

Consider $$\sum_{p \leq n} \log p \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p-1} \right\rfloor.$$
Using the definition for the first Chebyshev function
$$\vartheta(x) = \sum_{p \leq x} \log p,$$
we find that
\begin{align*}
 \sum_{p \leq n} \log p\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p-1} \right\rfloor= \sum_{p \leq n+1} \log p \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p-1} \right\rfloor -  1_\mathbb{P}(n+1)\log(n+1),
\end{align*}
so that we have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{p \leq n+1} \log p \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p-1} \right\rfloor 
& = \sum_{p -1 \leq n} \log p \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p-1} \right\rfloor \\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^\infty \sum_{\frac{n}{i+1} < p -1 \leq \frac{n}{i}} \log p \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p-1} \right\rfloor \\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^\infty i \sum_{\frac{n}{i+1} < p -1 \leq \frac{n}{i}} \log p \\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^\infty i \left( \vartheta\left(1+\frac{n}{i}\right) - \vartheta\left(1+\frac{n}{i+1}\right)\right).
\end{align*}
We apply a similar procedure to the sum
$$\sum_{p \leq n} \log p \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^k} \right\rfloor,$$
which, in this instance, we will be using the following relationship between the second Chebyshev function $\psi(x)$ and the first Chebyshev function:
$$\psi(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \vartheta(x^{1/k}).$$
Before we move further, we would like to observe that
$$\sum_{p \leq n} \log p \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^k} \right\rfloor - \sum_{p^k \leq n} \log p \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^k} \right\rfloor  = \sum_{n^{1/k} < p \leq n} \log p \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^k} \right\rfloor = 0.$$
Thus, we have the following
\begin{align*}
\sum_{p \leq n} \log p \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^k} \right\rfloor &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{p \leq n} \log p  \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^k} \right\rfloor \\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{p^k \leq n} \log p  \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^k} \right\rfloor \\
&=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{\frac{n}{i+1} < p^k \leq \frac{n}{i}} \log p  \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^k} \right\rfloor \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^\infty i \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{\frac{n}{i+1} < p^k \leq \frac{n}{i}} \log p  \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^\infty i \sum_{k=1}^\infty \vartheta\left(\sqrt[k]{\frac{n}{i}}\right) - \vartheta\left(\sqrt[k]{\frac{n}{i+1}}\right)  \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^\infty i \left(\psi\left(\frac{n}{i}\right) - \psi\left(\frac{n}{i+1}\right) \right)
\end{align*}
Thus, our original sum equals
\begin{align*}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{p \leq n} \log p \left(\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p-1} \right\rfloor - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^k} \right\rfloor\right) &= -\frac{1_\mathbb{P}(n+1)\log(n+1)}{n} \\
&+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^\infty i \left( \vartheta\left(1+\frac{n}{i}\right) - \vartheta\left(1+\frac{n}{i+1}\right) - \psi\left(\frac{n}{i}\right) + \psi\left(\frac{n}{i+1}\right) \right)\end{align*}
We can now turn our attention to the infinite sum; we can rewrite this as a telescoping sum
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{i = 1}^\infty i \left( \vartheta\left(1+\frac{n}{i}\right) - \vartheta\left(1+\frac{n}{i+1}\right) - \psi\left(\frac{n}{i}\right) + \psi\left(\frac{n}{i+1}\right) \right) \\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^\infty  i\vartheta\left(1+\frac{n}{i}\right) - (i+1)\vartheta\left(1+\frac{n}{i+1}\right) - i\psi\left(\frac{n}{i}\right) + (i+1)\psi\left(\frac{n}{i+1}\right)\\
&+ \sum_{i = 1}^\infty \vartheta\left(1+\frac{n}{i+1}\right) - \psi\left(\frac{n}{i+1}\right) \\
&= \vartheta(n+1) - \psi(n) + \lim_{m \to \infty} \left(m\psi\left(\frac{n}{m}\right) - m\vartheta\left(1+\frac{n}{m}\right)\right) \\
&+ \sum_{i = 1}^\infty \vartheta\left(1+\frac{n}{i+1}\right) - \psi\left(\frac{n}{i+1}\right) \\
&= \lim_{m \to \infty} \left(m\psi\left(\frac{n}{m}\right) - m\vartheta\left(1+\frac{n}{m}\right)\right) + \sum_{i = 1}^\infty \vartheta\left(1+\frac{n}{i}\right) - \psi\left(\frac{n}{i}\right) \\
\end{align*}
Since $\psi\left(\frac{n}{m}\right)$ and $\vartheta\left(1+\frac{n}{m}\right)$  are both $0$ for $m > n$ for fixed $n$, the limit
$$\lim_{m \to \infty} \left(m\psi\left(\frac{n}{m}\right) - m\vartheta\left(1+\frac{n}{m}\right) \right) = 0.$$
Similarly, we have
$$\sum_{i = 1}^\infty \vartheta\left(1+\frac{n}{i}\right) - \psi\left(\frac{n}{i}\right) 
 = \sum_{i = 1}^n \vartheta\left(1+\frac{n}{i}\right) - \psi\left(\frac{n}{i}\right).$$
Altogether, we have
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{p \leq n} \log p \left(\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p-1} \right\rfloor - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^k} \right\rfloor\right) = -\frac{1_\mathbb{P}(n+1)\log(n+1)}{n} + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n \vartheta\left(1+\frac{n}{i}\right) - \psi\left(\frac{n}{i}\right).$$
Taking limits as $n \to \infty$, notice the right hand-sum is a Riemann sum; we have
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{p \leq n} \log p \left(\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p-1} \right\rfloor - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^k} \right\rfloor\right) = \int_0^1 \vartheta\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right) - \psi\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \, dx.$$
We now move our efforts to the evaluation of the integral; $u$-substituting $x = 1/u$, $dx = -1/u^2 du$, we have
$$\int_0^1 \vartheta\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right) - \psi\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \, dx = \int_1^\infty \frac{\psi(x) - \vartheta(x+1)}{x^2} \, dx.$$
Rewrite this integral as
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{\psi(x) - \vartheta(x+1)}{x^2} \, dx = \int_1^\infty \frac{\psi(x) - \vartheta(x)}{x^2} \, dx  - \int_1^\infty \frac{\vartheta(x+1)-\vartheta(x)}{x^2}\, dx$$
Neither of these integrals diverge so the use of linearity of integrals in this instance is justified; this comes from the fact that $\vartheta(x+1)-\vartheta(x) \leq \log(x+1)$ and from Theorem 4.1 in Tom Apostol's "Introduction to Analytic Number Theory":

> $\textbf{Theorem 4.1}$ For $x > 0$, we have $$0 \leq \frac{\psi(x) - \vartheta(x)}{x} \leq \frac{1}{2\log 2} \frac{\log^2 x}{\sqrt{x}}.$$

Recalling earlier the relationship between the first and second Chebyshev function, the integral on the left is
\begin{align*}
\int_1^\infty \frac{\psi(x) - \vartheta(x)}{x^2} \, dx &= \int_1^\infty \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{\vartheta(\sqrt[k]{x})}{x^2} \, dx \\
&= \int_1^\infty \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{\vartheta(u)}{u^{2k}} \, ku^{k-1}du , \quad \quad x = u^k \\
&= \int_1^\infty \frac{\vartheta(u)}{u}\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{k}{u^{k}} \, du \\
&= \int_1^\infty \frac{\vartheta(u)}{(u-1)^2} - \frac{\vartheta(u)}{u^2} \, du 
\end{align*}
Back to our integral, we have
\begin{align*}
\int_1^\infty \frac{\psi(x) - \vartheta(x)}{x^2} \, dx  - \int_1^\infty \frac{\vartheta(x+1)-\vartheta(x)}{x^2}\, dx &= \int_1^\infty \frac{\vartheta(x)}{(x-1)^2} - \frac{\vartheta(x)}{x^2} \, dx  - \int_1^\infty \frac{\vartheta(x+1)-\vartheta(x)}{x^2}\, dx \\
&= \int_1^\infty \frac{\vartheta(x)}{(x-1)^2} - \frac{\vartheta(x+1)}{x^2}\, dx
\end{align*}
Before we proceed, we consider the integral
$$\int_1^t \frac{\vartheta(x)}{(x-1)^2} - \frac{\vartheta(x+1)}{x^2}\, dx$$
for real $t > 1$. We can rewrite this
\begin{align*}
\int_1^t \frac{\vartheta(x)}{(x-1)^2} - \frac{\vartheta(x+1)}{x^2}\, dx &= \int_1^t \frac{\vartheta(x)}{(x-1)^2}\, dx - \int_1^t\frac{\vartheta(x+1)}{x^2}\, dx\\
&= \int_1^t \frac{\vartheta(x)}{(x-1)^2}\, dx - \int_2^{t+1}\frac{\vartheta(x)}{(x-1)^2}\, dx\\
&= \int_1^2 \frac{\vartheta(x)}{(x-1)^2}\, dx - \int_t^{t+1}\frac{\vartheta(x)}{(x-1)^2}\, dx\\
&= \int_1^2 \frac{\vartheta(x)}{(x-1)^2}\, dx - \int_0^{1}\frac{\vartheta(x+t)}{(x+t-1)^2}\, dx.
\end{align*}
Since $\vartheta(x) = 0$ for $x < 2$, we have
\begin{align*}
\int_1^t \frac{\vartheta(x)}{(x-1)^2} - \frac{\vartheta(x+1)}{x^2}\, dx &= - \int_0^{1}\frac{\vartheta(x+t)}{(x+t-1)^2}\, dx.
\end{align*}
Now, in "Estimates of some functions over primes without R.H", Pierre Dusart has shown that $\vartheta(x) < Cx$ for some $C>1$. Using this, we find
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{1}\frac{\vartheta(x+t)}{(x+t-1)^2}\, dx &\leq C\int_0^{1}\frac{x+t}{(x+t-1)^2}\, dx \\
&= C\left(\frac{1}{t(t-1)}-\log\left(1-\frac{1}{t}\right)\right).
\end{align*}
Thus, by the squeeze theorem, we find
\begin{align*}
0 &\geq \lim_{t \to \infty} - \int_0^{1}\frac{\vartheta(x+t)}{(x+t-1)^2}\, dx \geq \lim_{t \to \infty} C\left(\log\left(1-\frac{1}{t}\right)-\frac{1}{t(t-1)}\right) = 0,
\end{align*}
so our original integral is
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{\vartheta(x)}{(x-1)^2} - \frac{\vartheta(x+1)}{x^2}\, dx = 0.$$

Thus, we have
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{p \leq n} \log p \left(\left\lfloor \frac{n}{p-1} \right\rfloor - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p^k} \right\rfloor\right) = 0,$$
as desired.